# PHP detect if it is a CONSTANT or a STRING before validating

Tags: php, variables, constants

I am working on a function to validate variables and constants.

```
function checkVars($var){
 if(isConstant($var)){ <--here is my problem, how do I check if its a Constant and or a string?
  return defined($var);
 }else{
  //use other functions to check if its a valid variable
 }
}
```

Is there a way to check if its a string or a constant?

**EDIT:**
The idea behind this is to save lines of code on recurring tasks like:

```
if(defined('CONS')){
 if(CONS > 0 && CONS !== false){
  //and so on..
 }
}
```

This is just an example but you could have 4 lines of code just to validate a constant or a variable to fit specific application needs.

The idea is to save all that work with a single function call that returns true or false:

```
if(isValid('CONS')){
 //do stuff on true
}else{
 //do stuff on false
}
```

Comment: `is_string()` didnt work for you here?

Comment: I don't think you can check if a value is a constant. If a constant is passed in, it would be the value of the constant. Unless the value being passed in is the name of the constant itself.

Comment: Please provide an example of how you are calling this function, and what you expect it to return.

Comment: my question is why would you want to do this what's the use case

Comment: @aynber you can test to see if you have a constant with `defined(name_of_constant)` and you can check the value of the constant using `constant(name_of_constant)`

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks. Learned something new today :-D

Comment: @TZiebura its useful to simplify the validation process of variables and constants, you can save like 4 lines of code just for validating each variable or constant that should fit specific parameters within you application.

Comment: @IncredibleHat it will always return true

Answer (score 2):

check if a constant is defined by her name:

```
defined('CONSTANT');
```

check if any value is a string:

```
is_string(CONSTANT);
```

logically, if it's not a constant is just a string.

for check if is a constant you must pass the constant name in string.
You also can check if exists a constant with the same value, using `get_defined_constants()`, but you will not know if is the same constant.

```
define('MYCONST', "THE VALUE");
function exists_a_constant($value)
{
    $constants = get_defined_constants(true);
    return in_array($value, $constants['user']); // true if finds or false if not
    // return array_search($value, $constants['user']);    //Will return the key (name of the constant)
}

function checkVars($var)
{
    if (exists_a_constant($var)) {
        echo "exists a constant";
    } else {
        echo "not";
    }
}

checkVars(MYCONST);
// exists a constant
checkVars('MYCONST');
// not
checkVars("THE VALUE");
// exists a constant
checkVars("random string");
// not
```

Comment: It returns TRUE even if the constant wasn't defined

Comment: i forgot to use only the user defined constants. updated the answer @CrashOverride is working now.

Comment: Still not working but I changed array_search for array_key_exists and works perfectly. Added it as an answer, thanks for your help

Comment: Strange. Works in here for checking a value. `array_key_exists()` will search the key. if you are receiving the key, you can check by `defined('MYCONSTNAME')`.

Answer (score 1):

You will use [`defined()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) to test to see if the constant exists and is defined. Then use [`is_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) with [`constant()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) to determine if the constant is a string. I assume you're using `return` because this condition is part of a function:

```
if(defined($constantName) and is_string(constant($constantName))) {
    return constant($constantName);
} else {
    // other code
}
```

Running the following test I could see that 'bar' was returned:

```
define("FOO", "bar");
$constantName = "FOO";

if(defined($constantName) and is_string(constant($constantName))) {
    echo constant($constantName); // 'bar'
} else {
    // other code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on André Walker answer I made a few changes and it works.

get_defined_constants gets an array with all the defined constants then I use array_key_exists to check if the constant you are passing is in the array.

```
define('FOO','bar');
function exists_a_constant($value){
    $constants = get_defined_constants();
    return array_key_exists($value,$constants); 
}

if(exists_a_constant('FOO')){
    echo 'defined';
}else{
    echo 'not defined';
}
```

thanks!

Comment: I guess your question was misleading/confusing. This has nothing to do with checking if a variable is a string, but rather you are only checking if that constant was defined.